# Sending emails using Gmail SMTP -- works, but security issues, so are there alternatives to Gmail?

Tags: c#, email, port

I'm currently sending emails in C# using Gmail ("smtp.gmail.com", 587) from my web application. While this works, for people using different computers with different IP addresses they encounter errors ("SMTP requires secure connection or the client was not authenticated") due to G-mail preventing sign-in.

Is there an alternative to G-mail that will allow other users (regardless of IP address/different devices/different computers) to be able to have emails sent on their end without issues? Alternatively, is there a way to salvage Gmail? I've enabled access for less secure apps.

Thanks.

Comment: Not on a corporate network that has outlook running.  Outlook uses a proxy server to get to Mail Server. The interanet (and gateway) blocks the smtp port numbers.  So when outlook uses port forwarding through the proxy server and other email server are blocked.

Comment: Does your environment have an Exchange server? If so, you can use that. If not, you'll probably need to setup your own SMTP server or rent one.